# Update record in Ember.js 2.4

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Apologies in advance, I'm very new to Ember and javascript.

I've been following the tutorial at https://medium.com/@jamesfuthey/a-gentle-introduction-to-ember-2-0-8ef1f378ee4#.mis7qdebs

He's introduced a pattern of creating components and putting all of the actions in the components and routes instead of using a controller. I want to know how to update a record in the database (firebase).

I didn't explicitly create an ID in my model, so I was trying to find a specific record using one of the attributes, but it's not working. I get the error of

```
Error: no record was found at https://taskline.firebaseio.com/tasks/taskname
```

Which I think is happening because my syntax for findRecord is wrong. I thought I was following the convention as described in the docs https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/

```
updateTask: function (model) {
  let task = this.store.findRecord('task', 'taskname').then(function(task){
    task.set( 'taskname', model.taskname);
    task.set( 'startdate', model.startdate);
    task.set( 'enddate',  model.enddate);
    task.set( 'banding',  model.banding);
  });
  task.save();
}
```

then additionally I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function index.js:26
updateTask
```

which appears to be thrown by the same function. can anyone redirect me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findRecord` is returning a promise object (because it may make an async call to find the record). The `then` function is where the task is fully loaded. You did set the task properties at the right place (within the then function), but you've called save on the promise instead of the loaded task. Your code should look something like this:

```
updateTask: function (model) {
    this.store.findRecord('task', 'taskname').then(function(task){
        task.set( 'taskname', model.taskname);
        task.set( 'startdate', model.startdate);
        task.set( 'enddate',  model.enddate);
        task.set( 'banding',  model.banding);
        return task.save();
    });
}
```

The return statement before the save is just to chain the promise object (save itself is also a promise). So if you would return the promise from the findRecord, any then called on that promise will resolve after the save is done.

Comment: thanks that's very clear instruction. There's still an error pushing the data up to firebase. so it updates the screen and recalculates some computed properties,  but data is not persisted up to the server.

Comment: When you open the development tools in your browser (F12), do you see any error showing up in the network tab when saving?

Comment: It doesn't write anything to the network tab, but I get this in the console `Error: no record was found at https://taskline.firebaseio.com/tasks/taskname`.

Comment: I guess 'taskname' should be an id, like a number?